# Bash only gives integer as output regardless of input when performing calculations

Tags: command-line, bash

When I type in the following commands:

```bsh
result=$(( ($1-32)*(5/9) ))
echo $result
```

the variable, result, always evaluates to an integer, whether the equation evaluates to a decimal number or not.  Why is this?

Comment: Related: [Why does division in bash arithmetic compute most percentages as 0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825574/why-does-division-in-bash-arithmetic-compute-most-percentages-as-0) (But that problem can be solved by reordering the operations, which wouldn't really work here because numbers like 1.65 would round to 1.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why let command doesn't work to add real numbers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440654/why-let-command-doesnt-work-to-add-real-numbers)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't think OP is using `let`, hence, it's not a dupe.

Comment: @Kulfy True but both questions are about about fractions / floating point math not supported in bash. Also consider `let` and `$((` can be used interchangeably sometimes.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Agreed. But as per [Ravexina's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/939302/816190), one does **expansion** while other does **evaluation**. Thin line of difference among them. But still I'm not convinced that it's a dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `bash` shell natively only supports integer arithmetic. In particular, since 5 is less than 9, `(5/9)` will evaluate to zero regardless of the other terms in your product.

Depending on your requirements, you might be able to do what you want (still using integer arithmetic) by changing the order of operations i.e. whereas

```
$ bash -c 'echo $(( ($1-32)*(5/9) ))' bash 35
0
```

if you allow `*` and `/` to have their natural precedence

```
$ bash -c 'echo $(( ($1-32)*5/9 ))' bash 35
1
```

because `(35-32)*5` is `15`, which when integer-divided by `9` yields `1`. If you actually want floating point arithmetic then you can use an external program such as `bc` or `awk` e.g.

```
$ bash -c 'echo "scale = 2; ($1-32)*(5/9)" | bc' bash 35
1.65
```

or switch to a shell that supports floating point arithmetic, such as `ksh`:

```
$ ksh -c 'echo $(( ($1-32)*5/9 ))' ksh 35.0
1.66666666666666667
```

(note the use of argument `35.0` to force floating point promotion).

Comment: `var=35; <<<"scale = 3; ($var-32)*5/9" bc` maybe helps explaining. It corresponds to the command line `var=35; echo "scale = 3; ($var-32)*5/9" | bc`