# how insert decimal number in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, server, bash

How can I multiply by decimal numbers and get the result in decimal?? How can the code be modified to meet these two conditions?
[image]

Comment: Please read `man bc`.

Comment: Please, don't use screenshots of code. Instead, paste your code into your question and format it as code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` icon (or the Ctrl+K shortcut).

Comment: Related: [Bash only gives integer as output regardless of input when performing calculations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108328/bash-only-gives-integer-as-output-regardless-of-input-when-performing-calculatio)

Answer (score 0):

You could call the desk-calculator program to do the arithmetic:

```bash
v1 = 3
pi = 3.14
$ echo "Area of Circle =" $(dc --expression="$pi $v1 * $v1 * p")
Area of Circle = 28.26
```

In case you aren't familiar with it, dc uses reverse-polish syntax:

- stack $pi
- stack $v1
- replace the top two numbers with their product
- stack $v1
- replace the top two numbers with their product
- print the top of the stack

These are equivalent expressions:

```bash
$ echo "Area of Circle =" $(dc --expression="$pi $v1 * $v1 * p")
Area of Circle = 28.26

$ echo "Area of Circle =" $(dc --expression="$pi $v1 2 ^ * p")
Area of Circle = 28.26

$ echo "Area of Circle =" $(dc --expression="$v1 2 ^ $pi * p")
Area of Circle = 28.26
```

Comment: when use this command>>> linux write: dc stack empty & pi: not found command

Comment: @Amanyahmad, did you first set the values of *pi* and *v1*?  Before doing the `echo …` line, try `echo $pi` and `echo $v1` to verify that they are set correctly. ¶ Also, make sure you are using the bash shell:  `echo $SHELL` should print "/bin/bash".